# Close an emacs frame and have all the open buffers migrate to another frame

Tags: emacs

Is there a built in command to migrate open buffers to another frame when delete-frame is called?

I see that there is a variable `delete-frame-functions' that could be hooked into to do this with some elisp code, but I wondered if there is already a way.

Comment: All buffers are accessible in all frames.  If that's not the case, perhaps you have different instances of Emacs running.  In that case consider using `emacs --daemon` together with `emacsclient`.

Comment: I see, my problem was that opening a file from Finder on Mac OS X was starting a new process. If I start the emacs server then the buffers are available in other frames befor and after the frame is closed

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan's comment points out, all buffers should be available in all frames. In my case I was starting a new emacs process when opening files from Finder, which I could fix by running `server-start' or running emacs as a daemon.